# WinRT & Light Theme

Tags: xaml, themes, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

How can I set my XAML Metro application to use the light theme (as shown in VS 11 Beta Platform Dock)
It defaults to the dark theme which I don't like

Thanks

Answer (score 16):

You can set the theme in app.xaml like this:

```
<Application
    ..
    RequestedTheme="Light">
```

Comment: The text become black but the background brush is still black.

Answer (score 2):

This link can be helpful if you haven't check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211380.aspx#creating_a_consistent_look_with_styles) yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this programatically by setting `App.Current.RequestedTheme` in the constructor of `app.xaml.cs`. Example::

```
    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        App.Current.RequestedTheme = ApplicationTheme.Light;
    }
```

Setting it at a later point in time throws an exception though. For more details: [Blog post about this](http://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/windows-8-winrt-metro-xaml-application-theme-dark-light.aspx)